# how to make the first block of 200 btc?

Tags: reward-schedule, altcoin-development

I would want that when mining a specific block was given an award that I pointed out

Want to make the first block 200BTC and all the other 50BTC how to implement it

It is possible still such variant
**block 1)** 50BTC
**5)** 200BTC
**6)** 50BTC

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to make an altcoin that has a first block which creates a reward of 200 coins. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Modify this code:

```
CAmount GetBlockSubsidy(int nHeight, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams)
{
    int halvings = nHeight / consensusParams.nSubsidyHalvingInterval;
    // Force block reward to zero when right shift is undefined.
    if (halvings >= 64)
        return 0;

    CAmount nSubsidy = 50 * COIN;
    // Subsidy is cut in half every 210,000 blocks which will occur approximately every 4 years.
    nSubsidy >>= halvings;
    return nSubsidy;
}
```

to read

```
CAmount GetBlockSubsidy(int nHeight, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams)
{
    int halvings = nHeight / consensusParams.nSubsidyHalvingInterval;
    // Force block reward to zero when right shift is undefined.
    if (halvings >= 64)
        return 0;
    if (nHeight == 1)
        return 200 * COIN;

    CAmount nSubsidy = 50 * COIN;
    // Subsidy is cut in half every 210,000 blocks which will occur approximately every 4 years.
    nSubsidy >>= halvings;
    return nSubsidy;
}
```